# How create two instance of fragment with different injection with dagger 2

Tags: dagger-2, mosby

I have fragment with observable injection & two observables (network observable and db observable) with same interface.
How I can create two instances of fragment with different observables?

**Update with code:**
I have two subcomponents with the same interface

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {DBModule.class})
public interface DBComponent {
  void inject(NewsListFragment fragment);
  void inject(NewsListAdapter adapter);
  void inject(NewsDetailsPagerAdapter adapter);
  void inject(HTMLActivity activity);

  NewsListPresenter newsListpresenter();
}
@Module
public class DBModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public RssObservableInterface providesRetrofitRssObservable() {
    return new DBRssObservable();
  }
}

@Subcomponent(modules = {ApiModule.class})
public interface ApiComponent {
  void inject(NewsListFragment fragment);
  void inject(NewsListAdapter adapter);
  void inject(NewsDetailsPagerAdapter adapter);
  void inject(HTMLActivity activity);

 NewsListPresenter newsListpresenter();
}
@Module
public class ApiModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public RssObservableInterface providesRetrofitRssObservable() {
    return new RetrofitRssObservable();
  }
}
```

First fetch data from db, second from api. And i have fragment with recyclerview to show list.

```
public class NewsListFragment
  ...
  component = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).plusApiComponent();
  component.inject(this);
```

I must save link to my subcomponent object for other work with mosby.

How i can create two instanse of my NewsListFragment to show data from db and api.

Comment: Please provide some code , I think using @Qualifier might help you.

Comment: @shekar i update my question with code

Comment: I don't get it. You have two Fragment and you want to share an Object (like RssObservableInterface) with both?

Comment: @sockeqwe Yes, i have two fragments, and in the first i want inject RetrofitRssObservable from ApiModule, and in the second DBRssObservable from DBModule. I can do it by if/else during injection, but i want to know how do it without if/else? And can i save both component in one property like two objects with same interface?

Comment: Finally i create two descendant of my source fragment with different injection like this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3f0aso/dagger2_injection_through_a_base_class/ctk7x49) And it is good for testing, because i can create fragment with test injection.